# Sending parameter to a #define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, directive, preprocessor-directive

I wonder to know is it possible to send a parameter to a `#define` macro for selecting different output

For example:

```
#define Row(1) LPC_GPIO0
#define Row(2) LPC_GPIO3
#define Row(3) LPC_GPIO2
```

Then in my code I create a loop for sending the parameter

```
Row(x)
```

Comment: Use an array instead.

Comment: Not clear what you want to do, probably another instance of [The XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Tell us what you really want.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How are those `LPC_*` defined?

Comment: I want to have different preprocessors that I able to select them in a for loop ?. the second part is not important because it could be different stuff

Comment: You could use parametrized macros to obtain several similar identifiers with numeric suffix. However, you want to loop over `x`, so using macros is not a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This macro syntax doesn't exist.

Moreover, it **can't possibly exist**, because macros are expanded **before** the compiler compiles the code. If your `x` isn't a compile time constant, there would never be a way to determine what to replace in the source code for the macro invocation.

If you need to index some values, just use an array, e.g. (assuming these constants are integers):

```
static int rows[] = { 0, LPC_GPIO0, LPC_GPIO3, LPC_GPIO2 };
```

Writing

```
rows[x]
```

would have the effect you seem to have expected from your invalid macro syntax.

Comment: "*This macro syntax doesn't exist.*" Well, using your approach `#define Row(x) rows[x]` would perfectly do. :-)

Comment: @alk yes, but that's a *different* (and very valid) syntax ;)

Comment: @alk Or a macro using a compound literal, for example `#define Row(x) (((int []){ 0, LPC_GPIO0, LPC_GPIO3, LPC_GPIO2 })[x])`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use macros

```
#define GPIOx(x) GPIO##x
```

and `GPIOx(1)` will expand to `GPIO1`

Answer (score 0):

If you want these calculated at runtime there is a way to do what you want

```
#define Row(x) (x == 1 ? LPC_GPIO0 : (x == 2 ? LPC_GPIO3 : (x == 3 ? LPC_GPIO2 : ERROR_VALUE)))
```

Though this gets messy as the number of options increases

Also, even if you do want this evaluated at compile time, most optimizing compilers would do that for you as long as x is a constant